# Android App keep crashing on long idle (API 24 & 23)

Tags: android, crash, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat

I'm facing a wired issue my app keep crash whenever it idle (after hitting lock screen button) but only on API 24 and 23 i have tested it on lollipop and below and it still resume properly

I encounter a documentation about the new battery optimisation system [Doze](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html)

But from what i understand this screw with Activity life cycle (OnPause, OnResume ...)

PS : I made the test with only a simple YouTube activity with no other components and it still crash

Java Source

```
public class PlayerActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
    // Initializing YouTube player view
    YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
    youTubePlayerView.initialize(Constants.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
    if(null== youTubePlayer) return;
    this.youTubePlayer = youTubePlayer;
    // Start buffering
    if (!wasRestored) {
        youTubePlayer.loadVideo("gsjtg7m1MMM");
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    youTubePlayer = null;
}
```

}

Layout:

```
FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

tools:showIn="@layout/activity_player">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

```
09-13 13:03:29.936 21317-21317/info.digibox.replaytv E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: aps
                                                           java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: aps
                                                               at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                               at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2517)
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2471)
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2374)
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2808)
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:2077)
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2431)
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2727)
                                                               at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:269)
                                                               at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:910)
                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2262)
                                                               at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1128)
                                                               at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1083)
                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1182)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
                                                            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "aps" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/info.digibox.replaytv-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/info.digibox.replaytv-1/lib/arm, /data/app/info.digibox.replaytv-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                               at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
                                                               at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400) 
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2517) 
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2471) 
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2374) 
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2808) 
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:2077) 
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2431) 
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2727) 
                                                               at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:269) 
                                                               at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:910) 
                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2262) 
                                                               at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1128) 
                                                               at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1083) 
                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1182) 
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947) 
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

09-13 13:03:29.939 21317-21317/info.digibox.replaytv D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-13 13:03:29.941 21317-21317/info.digibox.replaytv E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.digibox.replaytv/info.digibox.replaytv.activities.PlayerActivity}: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: aps
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
                                                                           Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: aps
                                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2545)
                                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2471)
                                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2374)
                                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2808)
                                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:2077)
                                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2431)
                                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2727)
                                                                              at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:269)
                                                                              at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:910)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2262)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1128)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1083)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1182)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386) 
09-13 13:03:29.947 21317-21359/info.digibox.replaytv I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
09-13 13:03:29.950 21317-21359/info.digibox.replaytv D/FA: Logging event (FE): app_exception(_ae), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=crash, timestamp=1505307809942, fatal=1}]
09-13 13:03:29.967 21317-21359/info.digibox.replaytv V/FA: Using measurement service
09-13 13:03:29.967 21317-21359/info.digibox.replaytv V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
09-13 13:03:30.205 21317-21317/info.digibox.replaytv E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: info.digibox.replaytv, PID: 21317
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.digibox.replaytv/info.digibox.replaytv.activities.PlayerActivity}: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: aps
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
                                                                        Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: aps
                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2545)
                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2471)
                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2374)
                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2808)
                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:2077)
                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2431)
                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2727)
                                                                           at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:269)
                                                                           at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:910)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2262)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1128)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1083)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1182)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386) 
09-13 13:03:30.218 21317-21422/info.digibox.replaytv I/FirebaseCrash: Sending crashes

Having problem formatring a create a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/thunder413/cfd837de83a45f1f2d306a033486b992)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with a complete Java stack trace and any code of yours referenced in the stack trace.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Just to confirm, is `info.digibox.replaytv` your app? Are you on the latest YouTube library?

Comment: Yes it's my app package and i'm using the latested Youtube library and i'm also using  buildToolsVersion "26.0.1" and targeting 26 with min sdk 19

Answer (score 1):

It's failing to find a class called `aps` when unbundling a `Parcelable`. Do a Find in files for "aps" to see if there is any mention to this class in your code.

Also, is it happening in debug or release? If it's release, is it possible that you have Proguard enabled in your build (could also be the case for debug builds, just less common)?

Try not storing the private field `YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer`:

```
public class PlayerActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        // Initializing YouTube player view
        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(Constants.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
        if(null== youTubePlayer) return;
        // Start buffering
        if (!wasRestored) {
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo("gsjtg7m1MMM");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

    }
}
```

Comment: It's a debug  and i don't have any class called aps (I did a find)

Comment: And any class implementing `Parcelable`?

Comment: Noop just the code above nothing else PlayerActivity is main activity extending YoutubeBaseActivity and loading a dummy video

Comment: Could you update your question with both your Gradle file and AndroidManifest?

Comment: Good, thanks. Please, try removing the private field `YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer` as suggested in my updated answer.

Comment: I did and still crash ! But i just confirmed an hypothesis I'm using my device (A3 2016 with nougat) when i plug my USB (with android studio opened) and pause the activity (lock screen) it crash when resume but when i unplug my device and do the same process the app resume correctly witch mean it's an adb related issue what do you think about it ?

Comment: Weird. By "pause the activity (lock screen)" what do you mean exactly? Could you describe it step by step?

Comment: I launch the app after i press the power button once

Comment: Unless this is a bug on the Youtube SDK (and in that case should be reported here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803 ), I don't see how this should make a difference.

Comment: I don't think it's related to youtube sdk because i did the test with a blank activity and still got the same issue i will try to debug further and will report this. Anyway thanks for the support much appreciate :) @Xavier Rubio Jansana

Comment: You're welcome! One last suggestion then: if it's happening even for a simple app like this one, try to look at all the logs, do not focus only in your app. Plus try with another device, or the emulator. Good luck!